# Read XML file from URL

Tags: java, xml, url

I try to read xml file from https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z020102.xml .

I added sout's with numbers to observe progress.

```java
public void wypisanie() throws Exception
        {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z020102.xml");
            System.out.println("1");
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            System.out.println("2");
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            System.out.println("3");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            System.out.println("4");
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            System.out.println("5");
            Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse( in );
            System.out.println("6");
            Element element1 = doc1.getDocumentElement();
            System.out.println("7");
            NodeList nodes1 = element1.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("8");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength(); i++) {
                System.out.println("" + nodes1.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }
```

This is the result:

```
1
2
https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z020102
```

My target is getting USD rate from this URL. Someone have other ideas how I should do it?

Edit:
I try use other URL like this:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml
and program works. So what is wrong with "old" url?
https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z020102.xml

Result of "old" url

```
1
2
3
4
5
C:\Users\user\IdeaProjects\NBP\untitled\abch.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have DTD file on your machine.

Try this:

```
    public void wypisanie() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/c001z020102.xml");
        System.out.println("1");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println("2");
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("3");

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        dbf.setValidating(false);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

        System.out.println("4");
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        System.out.println("5");
        Document doc1 = dBuilder.parse(in);
        System.out.println("6");
        Element element1 = doc1.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println("7");
        NodeList nodes1 = element1.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println("8");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes1.getLength(); i++) {
            if ("pozycja".equals(nodes1.item(i).getNodeName())) {
                System.out.println("" + nodes1.item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you did not miss closing bracket(s)?

Comment: when I copy whole your code I got compilation error, but when I copy code between sout 3 and sout 5 this compile and works!

Comment: can you explain me what did you actually do?

Comment: @darekdede1995, you code fails because you don't have required DTD (see first line in XML what you have received). In my code DocumentBuilderFactory is set to ignore DTD on parsing.